# How to create a webpage in django that allows the user to select objects, then display stats relating to said objects

Tags: python, html, django, forms, web-development-server

I'm currently trying to make a calculator for a video game. I want the user to be able to select characters from the video game, then the webpage calculates stats about the selected character. So far, all I have is a page that displays a list of names of every character in the database so far. I want a user to be able to select a character from the list, then the program grabs data about that character from the database, and does some calculations on it.

I have a solid enough grasp on models.py, and I have pretty much everything I want in there currently working. I'm I have no idea what direction to head in next. My guess is to edit both views and my html files. This is what my views currently looks like. The characters are named units, and think of class like a job class characters can take on if you're familiar with games.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Unit
from .models import Class
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    unit_list = Unit.objects.order_by("unit_name")
    context = {'unit_list': unit_list}
    return render(request, 'calc/index.html', context)

def unit(request, unit_id):
    try:
        unit = Unit.objects.get(pk=unit_id)
    except Unit.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Unit does not exist")
    return render(request, 'calc/unit.html', {'unit': unit})

#does calculations based on the selected character
def calcStats(currentUnit, currentClass):
    hp = max(currentClass.hp_class_base, currentUnit.hp_base + currentClass.hp_class_mod + ((currentUnit.hp_growth * currentUnit.unit_level)/10.0) + ((currentClass.hp_class_growth * currentClass.class_level)/10.0))
    hp = min(hp, currentUnit.hp_cap)
    stats = [hp]

#grabs the character and other info from the database
class unitSelect(forms.Form):
    currentUnit = forms.ChoiceField(label="unit", choices=[(unit.id, unit.unit_name) for unit in Unit.objects.all()])
    currentClass = forms.ChoiceField(label="Class", choices=[(Class.id, Class.class_name) for Class in Class.objects.all()])
```

```
{% if unit_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for unit in unit_list %}
        <li>{{ unit.unit_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No units are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Am I on the right track? And what else should I be adding, and what should I be doing next? I tried looking at django tutorials, and I've actually taken some web dev classes in high school and college, but I still feel like I learn nothing every single time. Are there any good resources you recommend? Sorry if it feels like I'm asking too many questions.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, You want to grab the data from the database & return it on the frontend?

Comment: kinda. I want the user to select a character, a character that is currently in my database. Then the program grabs data about that character and then does a function on it, just some basic arithmetic. Then it returns that to user to see(im guessing this is what frontend means, still new to webdev).

Comment: @Edmund He chooses in `index` page ?

Comment: The user probably would for now, but does it really matter which page the user would be using the program in?

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's dive in, First, Your URLs clipped from after .com are called endpoints, Let's call an endpoint in Javascript to get the data

- Add [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js) to your project like you normally do with any JS file, script tags..
- In the character selection, after character gets changed run this

  `axios.get('mywebsite.com/my_endpoint/').then((response)=> { // do something with response});`

Getting data from the server is simply by using GET-POST requests, You've created the views, now create a urls.py file specific to your app

```
# myApp/urls.py
from .views import unit # of course this is wrong, I'm just taking unit as example
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_endpoint/',unit),
 ]
```

this is the endpoint we're gonna call GET on, "my_endpoint/", and it will call unit function, Handle the logic of character switch behaviour then return HttpResponse or JSONResponse depending on what you need.
Btw, The technique of requesting is called AJAX, Which is ASYNC Javascript, We're calling the server without blocking the client, and waiting for the server's response.

If you're using jQuery for whatever reason, There's no point of using axios, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645505/how-to-render-a-field-request-without-refreshing-the-page/58645877#58645877) an old reply of mine which explains AJAX with jQuery.
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646656/ajax-triggered-request-doesnt-update-django-view/58646916#58646916) a side note you'll ask a question about in no time, look at this whenever you need it

Comment: I thought django worked using python? I dont recall every using any JS when i used django once in the past.

Comment: You manage the backend with Django but the frontend with JS, If you want to get data from database without using JS, it will trigger a refresh which I doubt you'd like to refresh each character selection that's why I didn't suggest it