# How to submit a form without refreshing in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I know this question may be duplicates of many in stackoverflow. But those didn't help me out.
I tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI) but didn't succeed without refreshing.

My `models.py` is:

```py
class Messages(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    messages = models.TextField()
```

This is my `html`

```html
    <form action="{% url 'messages' %}" method="post" id="new_message_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="">message</label><br>
        <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This is my `views.py`:

```py
def messages(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = Messages()
        message.messages = request.POST['message']
        message.save()
        return redirect('messages')

    return render(request, 'app/messages.html', context)
```

And this is my `script`:

```js
    $(document).on('submit', '#new_message_form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/messages/',
            data: {
                message: $('#message').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("New message created!")
            }
        });
    });
```

This results in MultiValueDictKeyError

Instead I tried

```py
message.messages = request.POST.get('message', False)
```

That only gets the value from the input and passes. But I cannot submit it without refreshing. Can anyone help me?

EDIT 1 - MultiValueDictKeyError

```
Internal Server Error: /messages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'message'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\Desktop\Projects\gcepac\app\views.py", line 17, in messages
    message.messages = request.POST['message']
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'message'
[16/Apr/2020 18:12:30] "POST /messages/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90361
```

EDIT 2
Actually the form is not even submitted when using this

```py
message.messages = request.POST.get('message', False)
```

This submits the form with the value 'False' in the db. Once the form is submitted I should get an alert right? So please omit this part.

Comment: If you could post the error message in full that will be better.

Comment: Try remove action from the form tag, I think you dont need it if you are making an ajax via javascript.

Comment: Even without `action` it is still the same. Only the data is passed via AJAX. But it is still refreshing

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Let's address the problem, There're 2 solutions. The easy one which is just a better solution to remove useless pain. put the script in your HTML file, And use this line

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{%csrf_token%}'
```

instead of

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
```

---

### Solution 2

The other solution is fixing your own solution. AJAX buttons are not submit buttons, They are just buttons, Remove the `action` from the form and change the button type to `button` and it should work.

---

**EDIT:** The problem is not in the `csrf_token`, However I wanted to show the first solution as an easier way to achieve what you need.

---

**BUG 2** Why is this not working, I've answered this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646656/ajax-triggered-request-doesnt-update-django-view/58646916#58646916)

Comment: Since I am already using the script inside a html form, Solution 1 didn't work. If I am going wrong with `csrf token`, I think i should get csrf error. And for Solution 2, removing the `action` and changing the type to `button` didn't make any change. Also, I guess the very first parameter `$document.on('submit'....` refers the type `submit` of the button. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, It refers to the submit event of the form itself, The button just triggers the event

Comment: Solution 1 didn't work because the `csrf_token` is not the problem as I said in the edit

Comment: However, the solution didn't work. Do your have any other working methods?

Comment: From your answer, I can understand that the newly created object cannot be rendered immedietly, But why isn't the form being submitted?

Comment: From my answer, AJAX can't return redirects, It's async, If you return a redirect, It will return the HTML of the page instead of redirecting to the page itself

Comment: But i still wonder, how did that guy submitted the form in that video! Anyways, Thanks for your time taking awhile.

Comment: There's nothing dark going in here, He didn't return a redirect, He returned an HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a problem on your script.

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken').val(),
```

If you copied that exactly as it is what's causing the error. Try this.

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
```

Comment: That didn't make any change. That was possibly a mistake while typing the question!

Comment: Actually this should have been a comment